# how to populate a postgresql database using text delimited files

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Sorry for the naive question but I am quite newbie to this database world, I have two tab delimited files that I would like to use to populate a database. However, I don't know how to make `foreign` and `primary` key to link one table with the other.

My tables are created like this:

```
/*A table for Variants*/
CREATE TABLE variants (
    varid serial PRIMARY KEY,
    chrom VARCHAR(50),
    pos VARCHAR(50),
    id VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT '-',
    ref VARCHAR(1000),
    alt VARCHAR(1000),
    compid VARCHAR(1000),
    targeted_allele_freq decimal,
    targeted_freq_factors VARCHAR(1000),
    exome_allele_freq decimal,
    exome_freq_factors VARCHAR(1000),
    rna_allele_freq decimal,
    rna_freq_factors VARCHAR(1000)
);

 /*A table for Annotations associated to a given variant*/
CREATE TABLE annotations (
    varid int not null,
     gene_refgene VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',
    func_refgene VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',
    refgene_transcript VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Transcript from RefSeq*/
    refgene_exon VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Exon*/
    refgene_nt_change  VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*nucleotidic change*/
    refgene_aa_change VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Brings all the aminoacids changes*/
    gene_gencode VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',    
    func_gencode VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',
    gencode_transcript VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Transcript from RefSeq*/
    gencode_exon VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Exon*/
    gencode_nt_change  VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*nucleotidic change*/
    gencode_aa_change VARCHAR(10000) DEFAULT '-',/*Brings all the aminoacids changes*/
    polyphen2_hdiv_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    polyphen2_hvar_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    mutationtaster_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    mutationassessor_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    lrt_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    provean_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    fathmm_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    sift_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    fathmm_mkl_coding_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    metasvm_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    metalr_pred VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '-',
    FOREIGN KEY(varid) REFERENCES variants(varid)
);
```

I know that when using `mysql` I can use the command `LOAD` to populate databases from text files, but my question is about understanding how this scheme works. In my tab delimited files, the one that I would use to populate `annotations` table needs to have a `varid` that matches the `varid` in the `variants` table, but how could I create a link between these two tables if my annotation file doesn't have this matched `varid`?

In my database the `variants` are unique when combining `chrom` and `pos`, should I create another column in `annotations` to match some column on the `variants` file?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL or Postgres?

Comment: Yes, you should create the other column in the `annotations` file. Then in PostgreSQL you can use the `COPY` command to load the csv file contents into the tables. `COPY annotations FROM 'annotations.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

Comment: Oks, thanks, so Do you need always to have the same column content in the two tables, otherwise is imposible to make the pair foreign-primary keys to work, right?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, that's the only way to do it and maintain the relationship while uploading from a csv. You don't need new, unique columns. The data that maps to the data in the other table just needs to exist in both tables for the relationship to be maintained. For example, `varid` needs to have data points in both csvs upon upload for the relationship to be maintained

Comment: @user2380782 If there's some other way to calculate the relation, you could leave that column null on import, calculate and insert the foreign keys, and then add the not null constraint.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, do you mean a way to calculate the relationship using column existing in table A which could map a column in table B?